# How to use RowDeletingIterator

Tags: java, hadoop, accumulo

I am trying to delete entries in my Accumulo table with the RowDeletingIterator, but the entries are not removed when I scan the table afterwards. Assuming there's a `row_id` entry in table `tableName` here is what I'm doing:

```
Connection connection = new ZooKeeperInstance(instance, zookeepers).getConnector(username, new PasswordToken(password));
String tableName = "tableName";
connection.tableOperations().create(tableName);
connection.tableOperations().attachIterator(tableName, new IteratorSetting(1, RowDeletingIterator.class));

// Write record with row key "row_id"
String row_id = "row_id";
Text colf = new Text("");
Text colq = new Text("data");
ColumnVisibility colv = new ColumnVisibility("");
BatchWriter writer = connection.createBatchWriter(tableName, new BatchWriterConfig()
            .setMaxMemory(memBuf)
            .setMaxLatency(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setMaxWriteThreads(numThreads));
Mutation mutation = new Mutation(row_id);
mutation.put(colf, colq, colv, System.nanoTime(), new Value("stuff".getBytes()));
writer.addMutation(mutation);
writer.close();

... //More work takes place

// Delete the record with row key "row_id"
BatchWriter batchWriter = connection.createBatchWriter(tableName, new BatchWriterConfig()
            .setMaxMemory(memBuf)
            .setMaxLatency(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setMaxWriteThreads(numThreads));
Mutation mutation = new Mutation(row_id);
mutation.put(new Text(), new Text(), new ColumnVisibility(), RowDeletingIterator.DELETE_ROW_VALUE);
batchWriter.addMutation(mutation);
batchWriter.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with the `System.nanoTime()` portion of the first insert. By removing that and having the initial insert be:

```
mutation.put(colf, colq, colv, new Value("stuff".getBytes()));
```

The `RowDeletingIterator` worked like it should.